# exclude value in zend form ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

how can I exclude the data that you receive in $ _POST?
This form is used to modify the user data:
The form must verify that the email does not exist, belonging to her which is already recorded:

```
public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $no_record_exists = new NoRecordExists(array(
        'table'   => 'user',
        'field'   => 'email',
        'adapter' => $adapter,
        'exclude' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'value' => '$_POST['email']'
        )  
    ));       
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'StripTags'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'StringTrim'
            )
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            $no_record_exists,
            array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 5,
                    'max' => 48
                )
            ),
        )
    ));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I include the exclude filter

```
    //include unique field validator
    $noRecordExist = new \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists(
        array(
            'table' => 'user',
            'field' => 'email',
            'adapter' => $adapter,
        )
    );
    $noRecordExist->setMessage('Email already exist');
`   $id = $_POST['id'];
    if($id > 0){
        $noRecordExist->setExclude('email != ' . $_POST['email']);
    }
    //you can add this validator to your filter chain
```

Comment: Where is $id?This function serves to me in the modification of the user, to exclude their email.

Comment: I had edited the answer to initialize $id, assuming this is submitted from the client side along with the form fields to identify edit or add new items

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the [\Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists Validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#db-recordexists-and-db-norecordexists)